# Execute SQL scripts in a required order

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008-r2

i need to create a small utility to execute sql files on SQL SERVER 2008R2, i have tried the following code

```
private static void ExecuteScripts()
{
      string sqlConnectionString = "UID=sa;password=passw0rd;Data Source=somesqlserver\\db01";
      DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\dxsh\);


      FileInfo[] fileInfos = info.GetFiles("1.8*");
      foreach (var fileInfo in fileInfos)
      {
           string script = fileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd();
           var conn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
           var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
           server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
      } 
 }
```

i will have the following files in the folder

```
1. 1.8_DatabaseAndUsers.sql
2. 1.8_TablesAndTypes.sql
3. 1.8_Views.sql
4. 1.8_KeysAndIndex.sql
5. 1.8_ProceduresAndFunction.sql
```

i need to execute the files in this order only, pls help

Comment: I suggest you should rename your files become 1.8.1_xx, 1.8.2_xxx, ... sort and execute it following ordering name of file.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the order in which you want to execute the files, just fetch the files in the order you expect:

```
string[] files = { "1.8_DatabaseAndUsers.sql", "1.8_TablesAndTypes.sql", ... };
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // Simpler way of reading files (and doesn't leave the file handle open)
    string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
    // using statement to avoid leaking resources
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(conn));
        server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
    }
}
```

Basically, you shouldn't rely on the order in which the files are returned by `GetFiles` - if you want them in a specific order, just enforce that yourself.

Another option is to use `GetFiles` but make sure the filenames can be ordered appropriately, e.g.

```
1.8_01_DatabaseAndUsers.sql
1.8_02_TablesAndTypes.sql
1.8_03_Views.sql
1.8_04_KeysAndIndex.sql
1.8_05_ProceduresAndFunction.sql
```

That way you don't need to hard-code the names in your program, but you can still guarantee the order, just by sorting the filenames before executing the scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there is a more generic way of getting files to execute in the required order, i have 9 DB's and each of them will have 8 to 9 sql files to be executed. can you suggest a logic where i will go by the file names

Comment: @CSharped: I've already done exactly that - include the order within the filename itself, then you can just sort them (e.g. using LINQ's `OrderBy` method, or `Array.Sort`.)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you do not wish to hardcode the file names into your code.

In this case, you should rename the files so that they are alphabetically ordered, which can easily be achieved by putting a number in front of their name (such as 01, 02, etc.) so the first file will be `01 1.8_DatabaseAndUsers.sql` and so on.

`Directory.GetFiles()` should return the files in alphabetical order, but you can use the following code to retrieve the file names and add them to a list, which you then explicitly sort into alphabetical order:

```
// Get a list of files and add them to a list
List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\dxsh", "* 1.8*"))
    fileList.Add(item);
fileList.Sort();

// Go through each file in the list order
for (int i = 0; i < fileList.Count; i++)
{
    string filename = fileList[i];
    string script = File.ReadAllText(filename);

    // Run your code
}
```